# Фильтрация фото в галерее

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, gallery

Пересмотрел много разных примеров, но не выходит прикрутить их к своему сайту. Подскажите пример как фильтровать фото в галерее по категориям.

```js
;(function() {

  // Menu settings
  $('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function() {
    $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
    $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var counts = $('#grid li').size();
    $('.col-lg-9 p').text('at the moment their ' + counts);
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $('#grid li').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).text()).show();
  });

})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <h1>Hello, my works below</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <p class="pull-right"><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">one</button></p>
      <p class="pull-right"><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">two</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container" <div class="row mt">
    <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
      <li id="one">
        <a href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a>
        <h2>Practical 5</h2>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a>
        <h2>Practical 5</h2>
      </li>
      <li id="one">
        <a href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a>
        <h2>Practical 5</h2>
      </li>
      <li id="two">
        <a href="proj/p5.html"><img src="assets/img/portfolio/cpp5.jpg"></a>
        <h2>Practical 5</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: что Вы подразумеваете под фразой *фильтровать фото в галерее по категориям* ?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку, к примеру, one - оставались фото с айдишником one, а другие пропадали, при нажатии на two - только с id two

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() { $('#grid li').hide(); $('#'+$(this).text()).show(); });`

Comment: @TerraTor просто [примите ответ если он является решением Вашего вопроса и если хотите сказать "спасибо" его автору, проголосуйте "за"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67844/discussion-on-question-by-terra-tor----).

Answer (score 1):

Они не будут работать. id может применяться только к одному элементу, к li в данном случае нужно применять классы, а не идентификаторы.

https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/dZywgb

JS:

```
$('[data-id]').click(function(){
  var items = $('#portfolio ul li');
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  items.hide();
  $('.'+id).show();
});
```